# Count column values sort by occurence

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a column in my table `users` that's called `user_model`. It contains different reoccurring names as, `value1` `value2` `value3` etc.

I want to count how many times all the different names occur and sort them by largest to smallest value.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  user_model, COUNT(*) totalCOUNT
FROM    users
GROUP BY user_Model
ORDER BY totalCOunt DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64f70/1)

Comment: Thanks, but how to print (echo), the data. I'm really a beginner. Thanks again.

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "Car:";
  echo $row['user_model'];
  echo $row['totalCOUNT'];
  echo "</br>";
}

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123456');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('testing', $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "select count(a.title),a.title from le7im_menu a, le7im_menu b WHERE a.title = b.title GROUP BY a.title";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $rows[]= $row;
}
print_r($rows);
?>
```